# Linux `apt-get install` with no candidate packages fails, but `apt-get remove` working normally

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, autocomplete

I have installed `bash-completion` by `apt-get install bash-completion` and then I set source `/etc/share/bash-completion/completion` in `~/.bashrc`.

`apt-get inst` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> becomes `apt-get install`, but when I type `apt-get install mysql` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> there is no candidate package, for example `mysql-server`. I have run `apt-get update` before.

Can you give me some suggestion?

Coment: `apt-get remove` works as expected:

[image: apt-get install no tips but the other is ok]

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure that your source directory is set up properly: In your question you use `/etc/share/bash-completition/completition` but on my Debian 8 machine the source location turns out to be `/usr/share/bash-completition/completitions`.